# single page application Template get bearer token function not working for grant_type password invalid_client error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, bearer-token

I implemented the default single page application template in Visual studio 2019, because I figured it would be the easiest way to implement a good authorization for a webApi. However the Token function, to obtain a bearer token for a webApi returns following error when called through postman.

`"error": "Invalid_client"`

I bet I am probably missing some config setting that I need to enable, but some extensive google searching did not bring up any working results. Anyone knows what is still missing to actually make this work?

[image]

Default Code behind is the Startup.Auth.cs

```
static Startup()
{
    PublicClientId = "Web";

    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };
}

public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.bunchofotherregistrationsfordefaultapp();

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely **not recommend** to use **SPA** template for set up **WebApi** authorization, but if you want to...

---

To accomplish this task you need to override 2 methods in your `ApplicationOAuthProvider` (inherited from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class):

```cs
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
    context.Validated(); // Set up your context to be valid every time
}

public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" }); // Disable CORS policies
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("email", context.UserName)); // Add required claims you want to encrypt in bearer token

    context.Validated(identity); // Return valid token
}
```

You can change validation or grant resources logic in these two methods to accomplish your authorization workflow. At least without any additional conditions we can receive valid access token.

Comment: thanks, I will try implementing this later today, quick follow up question though, does the postman call for obtaining the bearer token change in any way because of this or does that one stay the same?

Comment: Stay the same. Note that you need to manually implement validation logic. It means that in my answer even you don't have an registered user - token can be granted, because no validation logic exists.